# Change ZSH Autocompletion Highlight?

Tags: autocomplete, background, themes, zsh

I am new to ZSH and I'm having a little bit of trouble changing up some colors from the Autocomplete function. When the list comes up and I'm using the arrows to move around the options from the Autocomplete, the selected element gets a different background.

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to just change the color of the selected element.

I have only installed ZSH and oh-my-zsh. I'm currently using the bira theme.

Answer (score 3):

In .zshrc:

```
 zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```